# AnimateIt plugin console error

Tags: jquery, magento, animation

I have instaled this library

[link](http://jackonthe.net/css3animateit/)

But i have an error when the script is load.
The error is:

```
Cannot read property 'appear' of null
```

to the `line: 402`

in file `css3-animate-it-js`

The script was put on a store made with Magento.

Where does this error come from?
Has anyone ever met?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with your code and share the link of jsfiddle

Comment: Without code attempt there is no value of your question